# No Terminal in Spyder 5 despite installing Spyder-Terminal

Tags: terminal, spyder

I installed Spyder 5 on Mac OS Big Sur.

I ran this command from Terminal: conda install spyder-terminal -c spyder-ide
The command ran without errors. Still there is no Terminal.

I must have done something wrong because the Terminal doesn't show under panes. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for reading my post.

[image]

Note: I have Anaconda installed. If I access Spyder from the Anaconda Navigator, it has Terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To use Spyder-terminal in Spyder you need to close it, open Terminal in Mac or the Anaconda Prompt on Windows, and run the following command there:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spyder-terminal
```