# No Spyder-Terminal on Spyder 5.0.5 (MacOS)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder, anaconda3

I tried to install spyder terminal on my spyder.

**Steps oI followed (in iPython Console):**

```
!conda install -c conda-forge spyder-terminal
```

Then:

```
import spyder_terminal
```

And I get an error message that says:

```
No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied. You have to call load_stylesheet function after instantiation of QApplication to take effect. 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-fb5605fc26a6>", line 1, in <module>
    import spyder_terminal

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder_terminal/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .terminalplugin import TerminalPlugin as PLUGIN_CLASS

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder_terminal/terminalplugin.py", line 17, in <module>
    from spyder.api.plugin_registration.decorators import on_plugin_available

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spyder.api.plugin_registration'
```

I thought that it was because of the enviroment, so I tried to create a new conda enviroment with the spyder terminal module. I do as follows (in my terminal):

```
conda create -n spyder-env -y
```

Then:

```
conda activate spyder-env
```

And finally:

```
conda install spyder-kernels spyder-terminal -y
```

And I get an error that says:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - spyder-terminal

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Any idea what could I do to get the spyder terminal?

**Specs:**

- Spyder 5.0.5
- Anaconda 2.0.4
- MacOS Big Sur 11.4

Comment: You still need `conda-forge` channel in the second command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spyder-terminal hasn't been updated to work with spyder 5.0.5, yet. See here:
[No Terminal in Spyder 5 despite installing Spyder-Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67029991/no-terminal-in-spyder-5-despite-installing-spyder-terminal)